# Dropwizard stop maintenance?

Tags: java, dropwizard

I really like of dropwizard, but  have a old version of frameworks and not have maintenance for a long time, any have a idea if this framework will survive?

Comment: This is not a programming question or a question that can be answered clearly, but only rises a discussion. Have a look at the SO-tour on how to ask questions and what this is all about: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of activity on [the dropwizard-user list, the group is currently working on a version 0.7.0 release](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/0GbdDfPjT9E).